# Help with a regex to parse through and grab contents of <p> tag in html

Tags: java, html, regex, feedparser

I have a site I am trying to grab data from, and the content is laid out like this:

```
 <p uri="/someRandomURL.p1" class="">TestData TestData TestData</p> 
 <p uri="/someRandomURL.p2" class="">TestData1 TestData1 TestData1</p>
```

I am using Java to grab the webpage's content, and am trying to parse through it like this:

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?p1' class=''>(.*?)<.*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(data);

        //Print out regex groups to console
        System.out.println(m.group(1)) ;
```

But then an exception is thrown saying there is no match found...

Is my regex right? What else could possibly be going on? I am getting the html ok, but apparently there is no match for my regex...

Thanks

Comment: I'll just leave this here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If* the text elements contain multiple text lines, then it wouldn't find a match, because the dot (`.`) doesn't match `\n` (by default).

Give this a try:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?p1' class=''>(.*?)<.*", Pattern.DOTALL);
```